# JDBC doesn’t connect to Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The code below is exactly the same from a YouTube video, but it does not work for me. The expected output is to printout "connected" to the system, which means that JDBC is successfully connected to the database. But I get this error:

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

**The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**

Here is my code:

```
package sample;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Controller {
    private static final String username = "root";
    private static final String password = "";
    private static final String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println(se);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the JDBC successfully as a library, exactly like the video showed but it doesn't work. I saw similar questions on Stack Overflow but none of them solved my problem. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

JDBC version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar

[image: The database table]

Comment: That error means it cannot connect. It's not an issue with your Java code, but rather your connection string. You may want to try explicitly specifying the port number and confirm hostname, etc.

Comment: I tried almost everything I could find on the internet, but it didn't work, btw I am using a Mac but the video was done on windows, so do you think it's the same or it's different on Mac?

Comment: It shouldn't be and hasn't been in my experience. You could try changing the connection string to `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello"`. I'm assuming the screen shot is from something running on the same computer?

Comment: Try to replace localhost in your connection string with your (internal) IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but no luck still  :(

Comment: I doubt MySql is running on your machine or the credentials are correct. An empty pw on a Mac, maybe. I m not a Mac user.

Comment: Yes the password is empty. Most of the videos I've watched all show that the password is empty

Comment: Have you verified that a MySQL server is actually running on your computer?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot shows my database

Comment: Have you tried setting a root password and connecting with a password? It might be that your MySQL server doesn't allow connections without a password.

Comment: @Abdullah - Do you connect to phpMyAdmin using a URL similar to `http://localhost/...` ?

Comment: Yes, this is the URL: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db=hello&table=userNames&pos=0

Comment: @entreprenr I just tried that out, it doesn't work. This problem is only on my Mac, I just tried my friend's code, which works on his pc, it does not work for me. Btw I have downloaded a platform-independent driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal - In phpMyAdmin, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port'` and see what it returns.

Comment: Ok I did that and the variable_name is port and the value is 3306

Answer (score 1):

> Link failure means DB is not reachable, Kindly confirm your DB host,
>   port, username and password. If everything is correct, kindly confirm
>   DB server is running and has yet to hit max connection limit.

and you are using JDBC jar file, this may be corrupted. so check it and I suggest you, import JDBC using Maven

and you did not register JDBC driver. first, register it

by using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` this

here is one [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) for your help,

```
// JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
```

I assumed you put the appropriate [JDBC dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) in your maven file
and use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as class for newer versions of [MySQL-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html)

> The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL
>   Connector/J has changed from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The old class name has been deprecated.

Comment: No, this is not the solution for a "Communications link failure" error. In this case the driver is found, but the server is not responding.

Comment: I did try registering, it did not work, I got the same error.

Comment: Hey, wait wait wait, Maven??? I did not do what you said about Maven

Comment: You are using JDBC jar file.... Then it'll be ok.. anyway please check whether your database is working or not.. try to execute any query in MySQL terminal

Comment: Link failure means DB is not reachable, Kindly confirm your DB host, port, username and password. If everything is correct, kindly confirm DB server is running and has yet to hit max connection limit. (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-Com-MySQL-JDBC-exceptions-jdbc4-CommunicationsException-communications-link-failure/answer/Sachin-Khanna-29?ch=10&share=16d631ed&srid=u9Lid )

Comment: And remove your jdbc jar and import using maven... Sometimes your jdbc jar is corrupted

Comment: Okay, I removed my JDBC jar file. How can I import using Maven?

Comment: Is your database working properly?

Comment: If you are using InteliJ idea then follow these steps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#convert_project_to_maven

Comment: Yes my database is working perfectly

Comment: Did you import pom.xml ?  Is it working now?

Comment: Hey, I think I'll use flat files instead of database. But anyways thanks for Helping me out man :)

Comment: Btw you deserve an many upvotes

Comment: This is not the answer, the communications link failure is an exception thrown by the MySQL Connector/J driver, which means it was found and used to attempt to connect. That connection attempt failed.